# ubuntu pip install matplotlib installation issue(python3.6.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

Using Python 3.6.9,

```
pip install matplotlib

[ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -4:]
```

`pip` and `setuptools` are updated.

It reports an error and then continues to install the lower version of the package and then reports another error and continues to install.

The command is `pip3 install matplotlib`
Even without any proxy source and delayed processing, the result is the same.

The main thing is that it doesn't pause after reporting an error, but continues to download the lower version which is very strange.

Comment: Please be more precise: what version exactly is downloaded, what "another error" is reported. Ideally, a full log/output of the installation would be nice, but that may be a bit too lengthy for this question.

Comment: Do you have any problems running matplotlib? Which version of matplotlib do you (at least) require?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this problem with Python 3.6.9, but I can install Matplotlib fine. What version of Pip are you using? And have you tried with `python -m pip install matplotlib` instead?